# H2 Text stuck behind and not clearing DIV colored box

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am working on a clients website and trying to get the H2 font to not be behind the div I am using to create and orange box behind an image. I have a fairly decent grasp on while this is happening, but can't seem to figure out a solution.

```css
#srleft {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}  
.orangebox {
    height: 88px;
    width: 89px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 111, 38);
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
    display: block;
}
.orangebox img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left: 0; 
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="srleft">
    <div class="orangebox"><img src="images/quality.png" alt="quality service in portland and vancouver" /></div>
    <h2>Quality</h2>
    <p>With Over ---- Years of combined experience we promise great quality on all window installations.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems not necessary to use `.orangebox {position: absolute;}` ?

Comment: Seemed to have fixed the main issue from removing that. Ill admit I have copy pasted the code. I have been using css for a while now, but it always seems to do tricky things to me. Thank you for your feed back.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you remove `position: absolute;` because due to this code only it will hide those contents and make you look like that image only.

Answer (score 0):

If the div `position: absolute;` then for sure your text will not come in front of that div so what I suggest making table instead of background with div and making it absolute. Its better you remove `position: absolute;` or follow this code making table I hope that will work
LIKE one example

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML page</title>
<body>
<BODY BGCOLOR="Black">
<table width="750px" border="-100" height="230px">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="background-color:orange;opacity:0.7;border-radius:20px;">
<h2>TEXT IN FRONT OF BACKGROUND COLOUR</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "position: relative;" to your h2 text.